Getting error of misplaced constructs & variableDeclarator expected
I am getting error of misplaced constructs & variableDeclarator expected in below code while calling the method "twosum" from main method. What am I missing here while calling?
public class Sumofint {
public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
    int total =0; 
    int output[] = null;
    for(int i = 0; i<=nums.length-1; i++){
        total = nums[i] +nums[i+1];
        if (total == target){
        output[0]= i;
        output[1]=i+1;
        }
    }
    return output;
}
public static void main(String []args) {
    
    Sumofint obj = new Sumofint();
    int arr[] = obj.twoSum({2,7,11,15},9);
    System.out.println(arr[0]+", " + arr[1]);
}

}
I was expecting a normal call happening to the twoSum method

You can't initialize an int[] without specifying it's type like that. That particular syntactic sugar is only valid at array declaration time.
int arr[] = obj.twoSum(new int[] { 2, 7, 11, 15 }, 9);

or note it's convention to put the [] on the left hand side, like
int[] tArr = { 2, 7, 11, 15 };
int[] arr = obj.twoSum(tArr, 9);

Also, in twoSum, I believe you need
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++) {

Or you'll get an array out of bounds at the last position with total = nums[i] +nums[i+1];
Finally, I would simplify twoSum and return the first match scanning from the right. Like,
public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
    for (int j = nums.length - 1; j > 0; j--) {
        if (nums[j] + nums[j - 1] == target) {
            return new int[] { j - 1, j };
        }
    }
    return null;
}


Wow! thanks a ton Elliot. This solved my problem in a minute. Probably i need to get my hands on clear on arrays a bit i guess.

public class SumFinder {

    public int[] findTwoSum(int[] numbers, int targetSum) {
        int currentSum;
        int[] result = new int[2]; // Array to store result indices
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++) { // Loop through array elements
            for (int j = i + 1; j < numbers.length; j++) { // Loop through subsequent elements
                currentSum = numbers[i] + numbers[j];
                if (currentSum == targetSum) {
                    result[0] = i;
                    result[1] = j;
                    return result; // Return result when the target sum is found
                }
            }
        }
        return null; // Return null if no valid pair is found
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SumFinder sumFinder = new SumFinder();
        int[] indices = sumFinder.findTwoSum(new int[]{2, 7, 11, 15}, 9); // Example array and target sum
        if (indices != null) {
            System.out.println("Indices: " + indices[0] + ", " + indices[1]); // Print indices
        } else {
            System.out.println("No solution found."); // Print message if no pair is found
        }
    }
}

I added comments, so, you can review it

Well I didn't really liked the idea of adding multiple for loops. But above code helped me in removing null pointer exception that i was getting as i declared my array as null.
over here
int output[] = null;
I didn't declare the array properly. Thanks Lex

Just realized while solving that double loops do make sense and infact my solution was wrong. Thanks again Lex
